# How do I display an image on left of Material-UI AppBar, but retain the "hamburger" menu?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, appbar

I'd like to display an image on the left of a Material-UI [AppBar](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar), but keep the "hamburger" menu and have the image just to the right of that.

Is it possible? I can add an image to the left using

```
<AppBar title="My App"
        iconElementLeft = {<img src='header-logo.png' alt="Logo" />} />;
```

However, that *replaces* the "hamburger" menu, which is of no use to me.

I also tried creating an `img` as a child of the `AppBar`, but that puts the image to the right of any `iconElementRight` elements.

Comment: A related question is where does Material-UI recommend placing the logo when you have a hamburger menu?  I found discussion of product logo design but not placement (https://material.io/design/iconography/product-icons.html#icon-treatments).  When you have a hamburger on the left and a profile icon on the right it seems there no appropriate place for an icon.  I'm probably going to but it on the drawer that opens after the user clicks the hamburger.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just pass your  tag as the title. Material-ui will take a node as title

Something like

```
 <AppBar
    title={<img src="https://unsplash.it/40/40"/>}
  />
```

Working [pen](https://codepen.io/pranesh-r/pen/xRbXMW)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice. I did it the hard way and recreated the menu using and IconButton. Looks like I'll be refactoring that tomorrow.

Comment: This pen appears broken?

Comment: Issues when using TypeScript. Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

Answer (score 40):

In material ui 4.3.2, there is no 'title' props for AppBar.
So to add a logo try the following method.

```
<AppBar color="inherit">
    <Toolbar>
        <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" className={classes.logo} />
      </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

Use the css to restrict the logo size. i.e.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  logo: {
    maxWidth: 160,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 21):

Here's the MUI way

```html
import Logo from "../assets/logo.png";

<AppBar position="static">
    <Toolbar>
        <Box
            component="img"
            sx={{
            height: 64,
            }}
            alt="Your logo."
            src={Logo}
        />
...
    </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```